# Implicit built-in rules and header files

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have this `makefile` in a directory with a set of `.cpp`, each one representing a single program with some header-only dependences. All files are in the same directory.

To compile for example the program `a`, I do `make a`. The make's implicit rules will compile successfully `a` from `a.cpp`, but `make` must also remake the target when their header-only dependencies change.

However, once a program compiles, the following makefile doesn't rebuild anything if I do, for example, `touch utils.hpp` and then retry compilation. What's going on?

```
src := $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cpp")
exe := $(src:.cpp=)

# In case I want to build every program, w/o a cmd-line target.
all: $(exe)

%: utils.hpp test.hpp
```

My make version is `GNU Make 4.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last resort rule cannot be used to express the kind of dependencies you want. It is considered only if make needs to build something and knows no other rule to do it. Instead you should express this dependencies on your executable list:

```
$(exe): utils.hpp test.hpp
```

Comment: About "knows no other rule to do it", why `$(exe): ...` changes this? After all, `%` includes `$(exe)` and any other target, since `%` is a catch-all pattern. Why does make treats `%` differently? Is there any statement about this in the GNU Make manual?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: pattern rules are treated in a special way. If you read carefully the first paragraph of the [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) section of the manual, you will understand why your last-resort rule is not considered at all. And this is good: if pattern rules were working as you expected, make would also try to rebuild your C source files...